# How to select a particular part of the div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="inner quote" from="no">
    <div class="qt">
        <div class="from">
            admin:
        </div>
        ok bye
    </div>
    <div class="from">
        Me:
    </div>
    good bye.
</div>
```

I want to select:

```
Me:
good bye.
```

I tried using:

```
$(this).find('.from').last().text();
```

But this returns:

```
Me:
```

Comment: what is `this` supposed to be here ?

Comment: In your JS code what element is `this`, and under what event are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last part of the text you want is not inside `.from`, it's just a textnode following the element

```
var el   = $(this).find('.from').last();

var text = el.text() + el.get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hdptt86u/)